# react typescript how to correctly type a SetStateAction

Tags: reactjs, typescript

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-gates-ruxzr?file=/src/TodoAdder.tsx

so I have a simple todo app and I am tying to type the action that update the state of the todos, I am getting the following error , the error does not happen if I change my Todo type declaration to string instead of o union.
is this happening because of the union type on my `Todo` interface, I notice that error disappears when i use a String for my status object proprety

```
export type Todo ={
    name: String;
    id: Number;
    status: 'Created' | 'Completed' | 'Archived';
}
```

[image]

Comment: @NicholasTower hey sorry for the confusion , the useState is only the title of the todo , I have left a link to a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-gates-ruxzr?file=/src/TodoAdder.tsx

Answer (score 1):

Just set a type for `payload`:

```js
const payload: Todo = {
```